Keep RTI Connext out of single-package build
I am trying to build a package in Windows that includes a custom message type and eventually a service, but executing this from the Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt is followed by an error:
C:\dev\SmplROS2dNET2>colcon build --packages-select svc_msg_pkg
...
ERRORFailed to load RTI Connext DDS Micro
Link libraries: svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c
Link libraries: svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c
Link libraries: svc_msg_pkg__rosidl_typesupport_c
Install targets
---
Failed   <<< svc_msg_pkg

I do not want to use RTI Connext; the default fast DDS works just fine in what I've got to work so far, and I even have the environment variable set appropriately:
RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp

FWIW, I also get three of these warnings which only go away if I add cmake_policy(SET CMP0148 OLD) to my CMakeLists.txt file:
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/rosidl_generator_py_generate_interfaces.cmake:20 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
  are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_execute_extensions.cmake:48 (include)
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:286 (ament_execute_extensions)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

My message file, SettingAdjustment.msg:
string adj_type
int16 new_setting

My package.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>svc_msg_pkg</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>Package specifying </description>
  <maintainer email="me@company.com">username</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

My CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(svc_msg_pkg)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "Msg/SettingAdjustment.msg"
)

ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)
ament_package()

Please help me stop this ridiculous error regarding an unwanted module.  Thanks...

I believe I have excluded RTI Connext from the builds.  I achieved this by commenting out the following lines in the following files, to avoid calling what looked like any related batch files:
C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\rmw_connextdds\local_setup.bat,
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\rmw_connextdds\local_setup.bat:
call:ament_append_value AMENT_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS[rmw_connextdds] "%AMENT_CURRENT_PREFIX%\share\rmw_connextdds\environment\ament_prefix_path.bat"
call:ament_append_value AMENT_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS[rmw_connextdds] "%AMENT_CURRENT_PREFIX%\share\rmw_connextdds\environment\path.bat"

C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\rmw_connextdds\package.bat,
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\rmw_connextdds\package.bat:
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextdds\hook\cmake_prefix_path.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextdds\hook\path_dll.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextdds\hook\path.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextdds\hook\pythonpath.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextdds\hook\pythonscriptspath.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share/rmw_connextdds/local_setup.bat"

C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\rmw_connextddsmicro\local_setup.bat,
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\rmw_connextddsmicro\local_setup.bat:
call:ament_append_value AMENT_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS[rmw_connextddsmicro] "%AMENT_CURRENT_PREFIX%\share\rmw_connextddsmicro\environment\ament_prefix_path.bat"
call:ament_append_value AMENT_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS[rmw_connextddsmicro] "%AMENT_CURRENT_PREFIX%\share\rmw_connextddsmicro\environment\path.bat"

C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\rmw_connextddsmicro\package.bat,
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\rmw_connextddsmicro\package.bat:
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextddsmicro\hook\cmake_prefix_path.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextddsmicro\hook\path_dll.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextddsmicro\hook\path.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextddsmicro\hook\pythonpath.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextddsmicro\hook\pythonscriptspath.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share/rmw_connextddsmicro/local_setup.bat"

C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\rmw_connextdds_common\local_setup.bat,
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\rmw_connextdds_common\local_setup.bat:
call:ament_append_value AMENT_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS[rmw_connextdds_common] "%AMENT_CURRENT_PREFIX%\share\rmw_connextdds_common\environment\ament_prefix_path.bat"
call:ament_append_value AMENT_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS[rmw_connextdds_common] "%AMENT_CURRENT_PREFIX%\share\rmw_connextdds_common\environment\path.bat"

C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\rmw_connextdds_common\package.bat,
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\rmw_connextdds_common\package.bat:
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextdds_common\hook\cmake_prefix_path.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextdds_common\hook\path_dll.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextdds_common\hook\path.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextdds_common\hook\pythonpath.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rmw_connextdds_common\hook\pythonscriptspath.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share/rmw_connextdds_common/local_setup.bat"

C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\local_setup.bat,
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\local_setup.bat:
call:ament_append_value AMENT_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module] "%AMENT_CURRENT_PREFIX%\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\environment\ament_prefix_path.bat"
call:ament_append_value AMENT_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module] "%AMENT_CURRENT_PREFIX%\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\environment\path.bat"
call:ament_append_value AMENT_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module] "%AMENT_CURRENT_PREFIX%\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\environment\rti_connext_dds.bat"

C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\package.bat,
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\package.bat:
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\hook\cmake_prefix_path.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\hook\path_dll.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\hook\path.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\hook\pythonpath.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share\rti_connext_dds_cmake_module\hook\pythonscriptspath.bat"
call:call_file "%%COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX%%\share/rti_connext_dds_cmake_module/local_setup.bat"

I don't see RTI Connext mentioned anytime during the sourcing or building, but now if I try to build my message I get this in my stdout.log:
Generating C# code for ROS interfaces
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/dev/ROS2cs/install/lib/rosidl_generator_cs/rosidl_generator_cs",
 line 23, in <module> from rosidl_generator_cs import generate_cs
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosidl_generator_cs'

But, different issue, I guess...
